# Actors puzzle (Triple T)

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

**Which of these actors did I place last? Explain why.**

---

[image]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The person you placed last is

> Ian McKellen (centre photo)

First of all the actors, in order, are

> 1. Hugh Jackman
>  2. Lee Remick
>  3. Halle Berry
>  4. Gregory Peck
>  5. Ian McKellen
>  6. David Warner
>  7. Famke Janssen
>  8. Billie Whitelaw
>  9. Patrick Stewart

Each of these actors

> Appeared in either **X-men** or **The Omen** (O-men).

Then

> If we replace each actor with an **X** or an **O** depending on which movie they appeared in we get a completed tic-tac-toe grid as follows
>  [image]
>  For this to have been a valid game it must be that the two winning lines for "X" were formed at the same time and so the last placed X is the central one.

Title

> Triple T stands for **T**ic-**T**ac-**T**oe.

Comment: Gah, you just pipped me to this by seconds! Well done +1

Comment: @Stiv thanks, had to type quite quickly.

Comment: Nice job! rot13(gur vqrn oruvaq guvf fcrpvsvp pbasvthengvba jnf gung gur npgbef sebz K-zra sbezrq na K naq gung gur "B-zra" sbezrq na "B" (zber yvxr n qvnzbaq, ohg url :Q)